# Does the Overpowered achievement have a minimum squad size requirement?

Tags: achievements, xcom-2

I looked through the achievements today and noticed Overpowered:

> **Overpowered**
>   Beat a mission on Commander+ with a squad composed entirely of soldiers of the same class (but not Rookie)

In my second game on WotC (which was on Commander), I remember completing the Codex Brain Coordinates mission with only a single high-ranking ranger, but I didn't get this achievement. Since it was only one soldier, would I have gotten the achievement had I taken 3-5 additional rangers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that's correct. You need to fill up the squad (whatever is your current maximum squad size) with soldiers of the same class.

This [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/70ttly/psa_the_overpowered_achivement_can_be_earned_on_a/) claims you can get the achievement during a War of the Chosen covert op, thus only requiring 2 soldiers.